# Why does a glob expression passed in an argument net work when referenced as $1?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script called `TestList` and I want it to take the argument `Small/*.c`

`Small` is a directory and it contains files:

```
bar.c bar.h foo.c foo.h main.c
```

The goal is to get `Small` and `*.c` as seperate strings in my bash script but whenever I try to do this `*.c` always becomes `bar.c`

for example:

```
echo  `ls Small/*.c``
```

outputs: `Small/bar.c Small/foo.c Small/main.c`

```
echo  `ls $1``
```

outputs: `Small/bar.c`

Comment: please review [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then come back and update the question; in particular, provide a copy of a shell script that demonstrates your issue, along with an example of how you're calling the shell script, plus the expected output

Answer (score 1):

Mark your argument with quotes, so your call would be something like `./TestList "Small/*.c"`. This will yield the same output.

The reason why your command wasn't working as expected before is because * is a special character that needs to be escaped. Therefore, you can also supply `Small/\*.c` as an argument, without the quotes.

Comment: Note the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and the note therein regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before".